# Pylint complains with 'Undefined variable' for every variable

Tags: python, pylint

I'm using pylint 1.3.1 on my machine and trying to verify the following code inside test.py file:

```
def test(a):
    b = 3
    print(a)
    print(b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test(1)
```

It complains with E0602:

```
E:  3,10: Undefined variable 'a' (undefined-variable)
E:  4,10: Undefined variable 'b' (undefined-variable)
```

I think something might be wrong with the libraries pylint is using since I don't see why variables 'a' and 'b' are undefined.

Not sure what exactly could be wrong on my system though. I've tried to uninstall version 1.3.1, put latest, and then returned to 1.3.1 and started to get these problems. Anybody have a clue?

Comment: Pylint warnings are not the same as Python errors. I can't even see why it's complaining.

Comment: I don't see those errors with pylint 1.4.3.

Comment: Have you saved the file?

Comment: Can't reproduce this with pylint 1.4.4

Comment: This is a "bug" until 1.4.5, see my tox tests against pylint versions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226442/pylint-rules-how-to-solve-undefined-variable/35986139#answer-35986139)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue after an upgrade to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (RHEL7). It currently ships with packages pylint-1.3.1-1.el7.noarch and python-astroid-1.2.1-2.el7.noarch, but I managed to `yum upgrade` to python2-astroid-1.4.9-2.el7.noarch from the epel-testing repository. I resolved the issue by uninstalling the epel-testing package and reinstalling the stock package (in my case, by blacklisting that package in my yum configuration).